# Adding Select Top in a Statement from a controller of ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-express

a question on how to add a "SELECT TOP" query in asp.net mvc3

```
            var applicant = from s in applicantRepository.GetApplicant()
                       select s;
```

in my applicant there is i think 200,000 datas and i just want to select the top 50

is that possible? Thanks KUDOS! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the top 50 rows in any order

```
var applicant = 
    (from s in applicantRepository.GetApplicant()
    select s).Take(50);
```

if you want to apply ordering, say there's a LastName field

```
var applicant = 
    (from s in applicantRepository.GetApplicant()
    orderby s.LastName
    select s).Take(50);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300906.aspx) and [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb357513.aspx) accordingly. For example, to take second 10 applicants:

```
var applicant = 
  (from s in applicantRepository.GetApplicant()
   select s).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Take extension method:

```
var applicant = (from s in applicantRepository.GetApplicant()
                       select s).Take(50);
```